# webview delegate method is not fired in background process

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing one application.In that i am using my static library.And i run the app in background using below code

```
   -(IBAction)sendKeyValuePair:(id)sender
  {
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startTheBackgroundJob) toTarget:self   withObject:nil];
}
 -(void)startTheBackgroundJob
 {
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

//create the object for library class and do something and release that object.

[pool release];
 }
```

And int that library class i created one webview object and add that webview to my main class like below

```
           web=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
            //web.delegate=self;
            web.frame=CGRectMake(1, 1, 100,100);
            [web loadHTMLString:html_str baseURL:nil];
            [main_View.view addSubview:web];
            [html_str release];
            [web release];
```

Here my problem is if i set the delegate as self then app is crashing.And if i didn't set then delegate methods are not firing.And delegate methods are implemented in library class only.I want to set the delegate as self and run that delegate methods in library class.How to do this one.

Comment: Always Update `UI` in main thread. or Use `Grand Central Dispatch` it does things in background threads

Comment: How you manage the background task because when your app goes to background more than 5 sec then all the operation goes stuck until your app support multitasking

Comment: Before 5 seconds only app is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
    [web setDelegate:Your library class name instance];
```

Comment: Please pay attention on this "Here my problem is if i set the delegate as self then app is crashing"

Comment: Like this also app is crashing.If i set the delegate as my main class and run.Then delegate methods of main class are firing.But i need to implement the library class delegate methods.